# Best practise to create singleton in concurrent environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm seeking an answer to a question similar to [Is it appropriate to use AtomicReference.compareAndSet to set a reference to the results of a database call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992478/is-it-appropriate-to-use-atomicreference-compareandset-to-set-a-reference-to-the) but with different requirement.

The goal is to create an instance of `ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor` only once to avoid duplicate side effects. The construction must happen in `setUp()`. Multiple threads will call `setUp()`. Similarly there will be a `tearDown()` for reclaiming the resource from the object, which is omitted here. Question: what is the best practice to achieve the goal?

Simply using `AtomicReference` will not be enough, because the constructor will be executed first, so as the side effect.

```
private static AtomicReference<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor> ref =
  new AtomicReference<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>()

void setUp() {
  ref.compareAndSet(null, new ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor());
}
```

Using the answer from [Is it appropriate to use AtomicReference.compareAndSet to set a reference to the results of a database call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992478/is-it-appropriate-to-use-atomicreference-compareandset-to-set-a-reference-to-the) will not work, because `volatile` lacks of synchronization. There will be window that multiple threads enters `if`.

```
private static volatile ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor obj;

void setUp() {
  if (obj == null) obj = new ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor();
}
```

Simple fix would be

```
private static ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor obj;
private static final Object monitor = new Object();

void setUp() {
  synchronized (monitor) {
    if (obj == null) obj = new ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor();
  }
}
```

Similarly, DCL with volatile monitor may give better read performance. But both requires some level of synchronization, thus expect worse performance.

Also we can use `FutureTask`. It is more efficient because once the object is created, subsequent `FutureTask.get()` will return without blocking. But it is definitely much more complicated than `synchronized`.

```
private static final AtomicReference<FutureTask<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>> ref =
  new AtomicReference<FutureTask<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>>();

void setUp() {
  final FutureTask<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor> future =
    new FutureTask<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>(
      new Callable<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>() {
        @Override
        public ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor call() throws InterruptedException {
          return new ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor();
        }
      }
    );
  if (ref.compareAndSet(null, future)) future.run();
  ref.get().get();
}
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Use an enum? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java

Comment: Can you explain? Do you mean to wrap `ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor` in an enum-singleton? How do you know if the `ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor` is constructed or not?

Comment: `enum ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor {INSTANCE; private ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor() { /*your constructor here */}}` The constructor will not be called until the enum is loaded, which will happen the first time your code calls `ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor.INSTANCE`.

Comment: After reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2, I believe it is guaranteed that the constructor will be called only once. But because I need a thread-safe `tearDown()`, for symmetry I'd prefer `synchronized` approach. Thanks!

Comment: Yes the JLS guarantees that the constructor will only be called once. Nothing prevents you from adding a `public void tearDown()` method in the enum...

Comment: Problem is how to let multiple threads call `tearDown()` safely. I think I need to synchronize `tearDown()`, unless you have better idea.

Comment: I suppose it won't be called too often so performance does not matter and synchronized seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you only want *one* ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor. There's a question here as to whether 1) it's the side effect happening twice your want to avoid, or 2) you just need to end up with a consistent (singleton) reference.

Either way, `synchronized` is a good standard option. It will keep other threads from *constructing* a second instance, while the first thread is in setup.

If you're in situation 1), using synchronized is probably required. If performance *after startup* were critical, you could possibly consider *preceding* the synchronized section with an `AtomicReference.get()` fast-path, to enable the synchronized section to be avoided after startup is complete.

If you're in situation 2), then -- it's not really clear from your question -- there is a side-effect of construction, but you don't care about duplicating that -- just so long as the client code only "sees" a consistent single reference.

In that second case, you *could* use `AtomicReference.get()` to check whether it's already initialized, and return if so. Threads would then enter the "race section" where they would construct (potentially multiple) ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor. Lastly, there would be a `compareAndSet` so that only one thread set the singleton.. with failing threads falling back to an`AtomicReference.get()` to take the correct singleton.

Performancewise, a single call to `AtomicReference` is faster than a `synchronized` block -- but I'm not sure if, with the double- and triple-checking & construction of unwanted side-effect objects, the second approach would be. A simple `synchronized` block might, again, be simpler & faster.

I'd be interested to see some measurements.

Comment: It is 1) I'm trying to avoid. Updated question to clarify.

Comment: Essentially then, you need to _block_ other threads from entering the "Object with side effect" construction section. `synchronized` would be the simplest mechanism to block them, which I would believe to be the best. You "could" supplement this with an `AtomicReference.get()` to avoid the synchronized block after startup, if performance was critical? At startup, all threads but one must block so performance there cannot be important.

Comment: See @Bohemian's technique -- it appears it may be a winner if you need performance.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about [threadsafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threadsafe) [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) of the [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), here is a cool code pattern to use that accomplishes **100% threadsafe lazy initialization without any synchronization code**:

```
public class MySingleton {

     private static class MyWrapper {
         static MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
     }

     private MySingleton () {}

     public static MySingleton getInstance() {
         return MyWrapper.INSTANCE;
     }
}
```

This coding pattern is known as the [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom). It will instantiate the singleton only when `getInstance()` is called, and it's 100% threadsafe! It's a classic.

It works because the class loader has its own synchronization for handling static initialization of classes: You are guaranteed that all static initialization has completed before the class is used, and in this code the class is only used within the `getInstance()` method, so *that's* when the class loaded loads the inner class.

Comment: Interesting technique, but is this much (or any?) faster than a 'synchronized static' method with an `if (instance == null)` initialization block? It obviously relies on some form of synchronization or concurrency under the hood, I'm just wondering whether the more-obscure code form actually delivers any performance benefit. Any measurements?

Comment: Well, some quick measurements.. not a proper benchmark, but I'm getting 858 ms for a simple "static synchronized" lazy-init method, and 33.4 ms for the "inner class" lazy-singleton technique.. **that's 25 times faster,** if timings are not deceiving me. Kudos.

Comment: I probably need to benchmark myself for sure. I'm interested in how you measure the performance.

Comment: Sure! Here's an article on the approach, and how I benchmarked it: http://literatejava.com/jvm/fastest-threadsafe-singleton-jvm/

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Singleton in Java 5 or above version using Enum:

Enum is thread safe and implementation of Singleton through Enum ensures that your singleton will have only one instance even in a multithreaded environment. 
Let us see a simple implementation:

```
public enum SingletonEnum 
{
    INSTANCE;
    public void doStuff()
    {
        System.out.println("Singleton using Enum");
    }
}

// How to use in other classes
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SingletonEnum.INSTANCE.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: Enum is good for singleton does not need destruction. In my case, I need thread-safe destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the enum type for singletons, not only does it enforce the singleton elegantly, it also prevents common programming errors like when a singleton inherits a clone() method from its superclass and the programmer forgets to override it with a private method declaration. Or when you forget to override deserialisable, and allow programmers to serialise your singleton, declare a new instance, and then deserialise the old one.

Alternatively, if you use a static factory pattern, you can declare instance fields transient and use a readresolve method. This provides the flexibility if you might change your mind about whether it should be a singleton later in the design process.

Credit: Answer based on Effective Java by J Bloch (Item 3), a book every Java programmer should read, own and refer to regularly...

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized method would be the way to go. If you actually need the performance you need to restructure your code to have a single-threaded pre-initialization. Using any other form will cause side-effects as described in the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the FutureTask approach doesn't actually require all of that code; the `AtomicReference` is not needed, and there shouldn't be any need to call *both* `run()` *and* `get()`. So you can simplify it slightly:

```
private static final Future<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor> future =
  new FutureTask<>(
    new Callable<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor>() {
      @Override
      public ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor call() throws InterruptedException {
        return new ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor();
      }
    }
  );

void setUp() {
  future.run(); // or future.get(), if you want to get any exception immediately
}
```

Furthermore, with Java 8, the initialization expression can be written much more briefly; the above can be reduced to just:

```
private static final Future<ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor> future =
  new FutureTask<>(ObjectWithSideEffectConstructor::new);

void setUp() {
  future.run(); // or future.get(), if you want to get any exception immediately
}
```